# Cmake build failed with CMAKE_AR-NOTFOUND (cr exe not found)

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, linux-toolchain

cmake build failed with

```
CMAKE_AR-NOTFOUND cr libperfutils.a
```

When i checked build folder ar is not set.
x86_64-linux\gtest-native\1.7.0-r5\build\CMakeCache.txt

```
CMAKE_AR:FILEPATH=CMAKE_AR-NOTFOUND

//CXX compiler.
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/g++
```

How to set ar in cmake ?

Wheni see the cmake config below output . cmake automatically finding the g++
& why it not detecting ar

```
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.4
-- Check for working CXX compiler: g++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: g++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
```

When i check ar in machine manually its available.

```
/usr/bin/ar
```

Comment: What CMake version do you use? Is you trying to cross-compile? In any case, content of `CMakeLists.txt` (in form of [mcve]) would be helpful.

Comment: cmake-2.8.12.2 builing for x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

cmake ar should set in cmake lib build ,
temperorly  solved the issue by manally setting in my local Cmake file

```
set( CMAKE_AR "${AR}" CACHE FILEPATH "Archiver" )
```

Answer (score 6):

CMake should have been able to detect `/usr/bin/ar` by itself, but you can manually override this, with the `-D CMAKE_AR=/usr/bin/ar` option.

Here's the list of useful variables:

https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/cmake/Useful-Variables